# Drag and drop - Why do I get multiple ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION events?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I have an image in a fragment that I want to move left and right in a fragment. I want to do more, but I've simplified my code to show my problem. This is my code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    View imageLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.img1);
    imageLayout.setOnDragListener(new ImageDragEventListener());
    imageLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder dragShadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder();
            v.startDrag(data, dragShadowBuilder, null, 0);
            return true;
        }
    });

    return v;
}

private class ImageDragEventListener implements View.OnDragListener {

    int originLeft = 0;
    float originX = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        final int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                originLeft = v.getLeft();
                originX = event.getX();
                return true;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                return true;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                float currentX = event.getX();
                Log.i(TAG, "currentX= " + currentX);
                int deltaLeft = (int) (currentX - originX);
                v.setLeft(originLeft + deltaLeft);
                return true;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                return true;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                return true;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                return true;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is my output:

```
01-21 18:04:52.291    8486-8486/com.testdnd I/Fragment﹕ currentX= 971.14844
01-21 18:04:52.291    8486-8486/com.testdnd I/Fragment﹕ currentX= 671.39844
01-21 18:04:52.311    8486-8486/com.testdnd I/Fragment﹕ currentX= 982.2969
01-21 18:04:52.321    8486-8486/com.testdnd I/Fragment﹕ currentX= 692.3906
01-21 18:04:52.341    8486-8486/com.testdnd I/Fragment﹕ currentX= 993.28906
01-21 18:04:52.361    8486-8486/com.testdnd I/Fragment﹕ currentX= 714.4375
01-21 18:04:52.371    8486-8486/com.testdnd I/Fragment﹕ currentX= 1005.3906
01-21 18:04:52.391    8486-8486/com.testdnd I/Fragment﹕ currentX= 738.2969
01-21 18:04:52.411    8486-8486/com.testdnd I/Fragment﹕ currentX= 1016.1953
01-21 18:04:52.421    8486-8486/com.testdnd I/Fragment﹕ currentX= 760.34375
01-21 18:04:52.441    8486-8486/com.testdnd I/Fragment﹕ currentX= 1037.4375
01-21 18:04:52.461    8486-8486/com.testdnd I/Fragment﹕ currentX= 770.28125
01-21 18:04:52.471    8486-8486/com.testdnd I/Fragment﹕ currentX= 1057.3203
01-21 18:04:52.491    8486-8486/com.testdnd I/Fragment﹕ currentX= 780.16406
```

I get two events for each finger movement, and as a result the image flickers when I move it.

Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out in the end.

I get two events because I move around the image itself, and for some reason I get an event that gives me the distance from 0 to my finger, and another that gives me the distance from image left position to my finger.

The solution was to add a layout in xml that contains the image, and set the drag listener and touch listener on the layout, but move the image. This way, I only get one type of event, since the view that is being dragged does not actually move.